# Can't deploy Firebase Cloud Function with axios, ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED: Package subpath './lib/defaults' is not defined by "exports"

Tags: node.js, npm, axios, google-cloud-functions

`npm list` shows that I have `axios@1.0.0` installed.

In my Firebase Cloud Function I imported `axios`:

```js
const axios = require('axios').default;
```

When I deploy my cloud function

```
firebase deploy --only functions:DictionaryBuilder_English
```

I get this error:

```
Error: 
Failed to load function definition from source: 
Failed to generate manifest from function source: 
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: 
Package subpath './lib/defaults' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/TDK/L2JS/functions/node_modules/axios/package.json
```

Looking at the `exports` section of `package.json` for the `axios` npm module:

```js
"exports": {
    ".": {
      "browser": {
        "require": "./index.js",
        "default": "./index.js"
      },
      "default": {
        "require": "./dist/node/axios.cjs",
        "default": "./index.js"
      }
    }
},
```

I tried this:

```js
"exports": {
    ".": {
      "browser": {
        "require": "./index.js",
        "default": "./index.js"
      },
      "default": {
        "require": "./dist/node/axios.cjs",
        "default": "./index.js"
      },
      "lib": {
        "defaults": "./index.js"
      }
    }
},
```

That didn't help.

I tried importing `axios` like this:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
```

I tried uninstalling and then installing `axios`. That didn't help.

I replaced `axios` with `got` and uninstalled `axios`. I get the same error message.

I ran the http request from `RunKit + npm`, it worked:

```js
const axios = require("axios")

word = 'fall';
try {
    const response = await axios.get('https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/translations/en-us/es/' + word, {
        headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    'app_id': 'abc123',
                    'app_key': '1234567890'
                }
        });
        console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
}
```

Here's my Firebase Cloud Function:

```js
const axios = require('axios').default;

exports.DictionaryBuilder_English = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userID}/English/Word_Request').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    if (change.after.data().word !== undefined) { // another field could have updated
        let word = change.after.data().word; // get the search word
        word = word.toLowerCase(); // make the word lower case
        async function callOED(word) { // call Oxford English Dictionary with axios
            try {
                const response = await axios.get('https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/translations/en-us/es/' + word, {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json",
                        'app_id': 'abc123',
                        'app_key': '1234567890'
                    }
                });
                console.log(response);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }

        return callOED(word)

    } else {
        console.error("No word found.");
    }
});
```

When I installed `axios` I got the `EBADENGINE` error because I have `node 18.10.0` when `axios` wants `node 16`. I doubt that this is a problem because `RunKit + npm` runs my code in `node` 18.10.0` without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue today.  Fix for me was to upgrade axios-cookiejar-support to the latest (4.0.6).  The related issue on the axios github issues has been closed, otherwise I would have responded to the person who asked about this last week.